# Logical expression that can catch i'th bit in 16-bit binary that corresponds to an integer value?

Tags: python-3.x, binary, logical-operators, 16-bit

I'm currently working on the last project in Nand2Tetris course.
I've been trying to figure out how the logic expression works while implementing a bit-wise calculation.

How Python can catch the right digits of 16-bit binary that correspond to an integer `y` when the `twoToThe[i] == 0` (5 is 101 in binary, thus `twoToThe[0] == 0` and `twoToThe[2] == 0` are `False` and it's the right answer)
but why does not show the exact opposite result when `twoToThe[i] == 1`?
I thought it would return `True` on both `twoTwoThe[0] == 1` and `twoTwoThe[2] == 1`

Here's code below

```py
# Calculating x * y
x = 3 # doesn't matter here
y = 5
# Array that holds i'th bit's integer values in 16-bit binary (e.g. twoToThe[4] = 16)
twoToThe = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768]

## Set twoToThe[i] == 0
print(y & twoToThe[0] == 0) # False (101 is 5, so False is right)
print(y & twoToThe[1] == 0) # True
print(y & twoToThe[2] == 0) # False (101 is 5, so False is right)
print(y & twoToThe[3] == 0) # True
print(y & twoToThe[4] == 0) # True
print(y & twoToThe[5] == 0) # True
...
print(y & twoToThe[15] == 1) # False


## Set twoToThe[i] == 1
print(y & twoToThe[0] == 1) # True
print(y & twoToThe[1] == 1) # False
print(y & twoToThe[2] == 1) # False (I expected True here, but it's false)
print(y & twoToThe[3] == 1) # False
print(y & twoToThe[4] == 1) # False
print(y & twoToThe[5] == 1) # False
...
print(y & twoToThe[15] == 1) # False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `y & twoToThe[0]` expressions evaluates to a new integer (as a result of a bitwise and operation between the bits of `5` and the bits of `twoToThe[i]`), not to a boolean as I think you were expecting. Check it:

```
y = 5
# Array that holds i'th bit's integer values in 16-bit binary (e.g. twoToThe[4] = 16)
twoToThe = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096, 8192, 16384, 32768]

print(type(y & twoToThe[0])) #int

print(y & twoToThe[0]) # 1
print(y & twoToThe[1]) # 0
print(y & twoToThe[2]) # 4
print(y & twoToThe[3]) # 0
print(y & twoToThe[4]) # 0
print(y & twoToThe[5]) # 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your insight. Having boolean value is what I need to do a bit-wise calculation, not an integer calculation. All I'm asking here is that how the logic of `y & twoToThe[i] == 0` works in Python(sort of a mechanism) thus it returns the right answer (5 is 101 in binary, and as you see above, when i = 0 and i = 2,  `y & twoToThe[i] == 0` returns `False` which is true), but it doesn't work when  `y & twoToThe[i] == 1`(I expected that when i=0 and i=2 it would return True) as you can see. Maybe my explanation was not enough.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear. The expression `y & twoToThe[2]` evaluates to 4 (101 & 100=100) so when compared to 1 it returns False. Is it clear now?